# Should the resolve map redirect to the 'otherwise' location during the first ui-router request?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have found the resolve map incredibly useful. If I request a state change within a page, if any resolves fail the state will not conclude/succeed as expected.

I do not seem to be performing anything within my app that would affect this behaviour, but I noticed that if I attempt to load a state directly in my app (through URL, eg. **app.com/my/state**) and the resolves fail, there is no state to fallback to, seeings this is the first route requested.

I would have assumed it would fallback to my 'otherwise' location, which is defined as '/'. Is this expected functionality? If not, is there an efficient way to handle this?

My current solution involves catching state errors and setting the location if there isn't a fromState (meaning the error occurred on the first state)

```
EbApp.run([
    '$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $location, $timeout)
    {
        var first_state_error = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState)
        {
            // Redirect to the app root on a state error during the first state request
            if ( ! fromState.name) {
                $timeout(function()
                {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function()
                    {
                        $location.path('/').search({});
                    });
                });
            }
            // Remove watching state change errors once there is a fromState available
            else {
                first_state_error();
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your state resolve function fails you don't go to "otherwise" route because the stateManager has found the route **to** go.
What you have to test is the toState name (not fromState), if you want to have different routes for errors, something like this:

```
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            if (toState.name === 'yourRouteName') {
                return $state.go('whereverRoute');
            }
            return error;
        });
```

or simply

```
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            $location.path('/')
        });
```

if you want always redirect to your root

Comment: Thanks @wilver. While this is a great way to handle errors, I don't intend on showing error pages. When states fail to resolve when navigating the app, the state remains unchanged, though this is where the issue lies, when a URL is requested as the first state when it ends up failing.